# Reading images and approximating and recreating each pixel with closest colours?

Tags: c++, python, cgi, pixel, approximation

http://pastebin.com/v0B3Vje2
I'm looking for a way to get pixels from an image, then find the closest color to that in another program(I can compile it into the source of the "Another program"; perfect if compatible without source injection) and then use that color and put it to a correct pixel. Basically, Script/Code/Executable takes an image file for example, then re-creates each pixel with the closest matches. The program I'm talking about is The Powder Toy. (powdertoy.co.uk). If you know it, I am using it for private purposes and proof-of-concept, as the "public saves" can't have CGI in them. JoJoBond, one of the users there, is permitted to do this, as he/she did it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to load an image and extract the pixel color values:

```
import Image

img = Image.open('random.png')
width, height = img.size
pixels = img.getdata()
print 'pixels:'
for i, px in enumerate(img.getdata()):

    # decide whether to replace this pixel

    # call out to external program to translate color value
    r, g, b = px
    npx = (b, g, r)

    # replace pixel with new color value        
    y = i / width
    x = i % width
    img.putpixel((x, y), npx)

    print px, npx
```

Output:

```
pixels:
(58, 0, 0) (0, 0, 58)
(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 4) (4, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)
(0, 245, 0) (0, 245, 0)
(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 0)
(14, 0, 0) (0, 0, 14)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use [scipy.cluster.vq.vq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html#scipy.cluster.vq.vq) to quantize the image:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.vq as vq
import Image
import random

img = Image.open('cartoon.png').convert('RGB')
arr = np.asarray(img)
shape_orig = arr.shape

# make arr a 2D array
arr = arr.reshape(-1,3)

# create an array of all the colors in the image
palette=np.unique(arr.ravel().view([('r',np.uint8),('g',np.uint8),('b',np.uint8)]))
# randomly select 50 colors from the palette
palette=palette[random.sample(range(len(palette)),50)]

# make palette a 2D array
palette=palette.view('uint8').reshape(-1,3)

# Quantize arr to the closet color in palette
code,dist=vq.vq(arr,palette)
arr_quantized=palette[code]

# make arr_quantized have the same shape as arr
arr_quantized=arr_quantized.reshape(shape_orig)
img_new=Image.fromarray(arr_quantized)
img_new.save('/tmp/cartoon_quantized.png')
```

with cartoon.png:

[image]

the above code produces cartoon_quantized.png:

[image]

Note: I'm not well-versed on what the best way to define close colors is.

The above code uses `vq.vq` to chose the color in the palette that has the smallest Euclidean distance to the color in the given image.
I'm not sure -- in fact I doubt -- that using Euclidean distance with RGB-tuples is the best way to define close colors.

You might want to choose a different color system than RGB, and maybe even a different metric than Euclidean distance. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it's possible to use `vq.vq` if you need a different metric than Euclidean distance...

Comment: Euclidean distance with RGB isn't bad. Better would be to use a perceptually consistent color space like LAB but that's a lot of work for not much gain.

Comment: Regardless of the distance metric used, selecting N random samples to match with doesn't seem like a good approach. Offhand I think you'd want to pick some that would tend to minimize the color-error being introduced -- maybe the N most popular colors?

Comment: Is there a way to get the closest colour fron a pool of HEX values? (I could get the HEX values from Powder Toy's each element and make an array of them)

Comment: @Boxmein: Sure. You would want to convert the HEX values to RGB-triplets with values between 0--255. If you had N Hex values, you'd want `palette` to be an (N,3) ndarray. Once you've defined `palette`, the rest of the code could be used unchanged.